# SimpleXML addChild Errors

Tags: xml, simplexml, php

I've been trying to make a PHP script that edits an XML file which is used to change a navigation bar for a website. However, whenever most of the time I run this code, it reports a bunch of errors:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Volumes/web/edit/includes/new-page.php on line 96
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Volumes/web/edit/includes/new-page.php on line 96
>
> Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of SimpleXMLElement has no effect in /Volumes/web/edit/includes/new-page.php on line 110
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in /Volumes/web/edit/includes/new-page.php on line 113

Below is the part of the script that I'm having trouble with. Sorry if it's a bit messy or strange, as I am new to XML. All it is supposed to do is get all the children of a certain element, add one more child, sort them alphabetically, and put them back into the XML file.

```
$nxml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile) or die ("Unable to load XML file!");

$items = array();
foreach ($nxml->$parent->part[$navpartnum]->item as $item1) { //Line 96
    $items[] .= "{$item1->title} - {$item1->link}";
}

$items[] .= "{$title} - {$navpointer}";

sort($items);

$navparts = array();
foreach ( $items as $item2 ) {
    $itemparts = explode(" - ",$item2);
    $navparts[$itemparts[0]] = $itemparts[1];
}

unset($nxml->$parent->part[$navpartnum]->item); //Line 110

foreach( $navparts as $akey => $avalue ) {
    $makeitem = $nxml->$parent->part[$navpartnum]->addChild('item'); //Line 113
    $makeitem->addChild('title',$akey);
    $makeitem->addChild('link',$avalue);
}

file_put_contents($xmlfile, $nxml->asXML());
```

And here is an example input that the above script gets.

```
$xmlfile    = "/Volumes/web/nav.xml";
$navpartnum = 0;
$parent     = "about";
$title      = "Contact";
$navpointer = "/about/contact/";
```

And finally, here a sample of the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navbar>
<about parts="2">
    <part num="1">
        <item>
            <title>Overview</title>
            <link>/about/overview/</link>
        </item>
    </part>
    <part num="2">
        <item>
            <title>Activities and Athletics</title>
            <link>/about/activities_and_athletics/</link>
        </item>
    </part>
</about>
</navbar>
```

This script worked a few times, but now it just shows the errors I said before. Also I'm using PHP 5.4.10. Any ideas as to what might be the problem?

Comment: Did you try to dump `$nxml->$parent->part[$navpartnum]`?

Comment: @Uby a var_dump of `$nxml->$parent->part[$navpartnum]` just before line 110 is giving me `NULL`

Comment: Well, then you're not getting what you expected, you should debug your code.

Comment: Yes you need to debug and check the variables before using them because from what you outlined in your question, it *just works* (tm). See: http://eval.in/private/3661caef0e68f7 - that is your XML + code and there is no problem at all.

Comment: @hakre Hey thanks a lot, turns out the problem was with the input and not the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the script is fine and the input is actually wrong. After looking through the script and dumping every variable for the hundredth time, I realized that `$navpartnum` was actually a string instead of a number. So apparently simpleXML was looking for an element named `"0"` instead of looking for the element with an index of `0`. Whoops!

Comment: Yes simplexml differs between numbers (the nth element) and strings (attribute of an element, if multiple elements, of the first one).

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

```
foreach ($nxml->$parent->part[$navpartnum]->item as $item1) { //Line 96
```

you reported this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Volumes/web/edit/includes/new-page.php on line 96
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Volumes/web/edit/includes/new-page.php on line 96

That just means you expect data to be somewhere where it is not. SimpleXML does not throw any exceptions telling your right away so when this is not stable you need to keep care on your own:

```
$items = $nxml->$parent->part[$navpartnum]->item;
if (!($items instanceof SimpleXMLElement)) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to obtain items.');
}

foreach ($items as $item1) {
   ...
}
```

This is just explicit error checking early on. You might want to review also why things don't work, e.g. take a peek into the XML. I suggest you create yourself a formatting function for that because SimpleXML's XML output can not be formatted by default and so it's harder to read:

```
$nxml->asXML('php://stdout');
```

or

```
$nxml->asXML('php://stderr');
```

to put it out into the error stream.